# What is the equivalent of a map of maps in C#

Tags: c#, c++

In C++ I am using `map<string, map<string, string>> Any_name;`. What is the equivalent of this in C#?

Comment: this is not a multimap. it is a map with the value type of a map. a multi map is map which can contain few values for the same keys, or few same keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`, documention on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Updated the sample based on comment :

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> map = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
map["test1"] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
map["test1"]["test2"] = "anything";
```

Comment: i used it but i got this error (System.NullReferenceException) when i want to save something like data["test1"]["test2"] = "anything";

Comment: You should initiliaze the dictionary before, check the updated code sample in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since std::map is sorted, the C# (.NET in general) equivalent is SortedDictionary:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, string>> Any_name = new SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, string>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IMultiMap<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerable<TValue> this[TKey key] { get; set; }
    int Count { get; }
    IEnumerable<TKey> Keys { get; }
    IEnumerable<TValue> Values { get; }

    void Add(TKey key, TValue value);
    void Clear();
    bool Contains(TKey Key, TValue value);
    bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item);
    bool ContainsKey(TKey key);
    bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item);
    bool Remove(TKey key);
    bool Remove(TKey key, TValue value);
    bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out IEnumerable<TValue> value);
}

public class MultiMap<TKey, TValue> : IMultiMap<TKey, TValue>
{
    private SortedDictionary<TKey, SortedSet<TValue>> _Items;

    public MultiMap()
    {
        _Items = new SortedDictionary<TKey, SortedSet<TValue>>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TValue> this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items[key];
        }

        set
        {
            _Items[key] = new SortedSet<TValue>(value);
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).Count();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items.Keys;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TValue> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value);
        }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (!_Items.ContainsKey(key))
            _Items.Add(key, new SortedSet<TValue>());

        _Items[key].Add(value);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _Items.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return Contains(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public bool Contains(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        return _Items.ContainsKey(key) && _Items[key].Contains(value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _Items.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {            
        return _Items.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(kvp.Key, v))).GetEnumerator();            
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        return _Items.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return Remove(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (!_Items.ContainsKey(key))
            return false;

        return _Items[key].Remove(value);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out IEnumerable<TValue> value)
    {
        bool isPresent = _Items.ContainsKey(key);
        value = isPresent ? _Items[key] : null;
        return isPresent;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.